# NSTimer Countdown - updateCounter Swift 3.0 New Syntax?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, nstimer, swift3

I have a simple countdown timer. And a label that displays the countdown.

```
var swiftTimer = NSTimer()
var swiftCounter = 60

override func viewDidLoad() {

timerLabel.text = String(swiftCounter)

}
```

I reduce the counter by one second. This function gives me an error:

```
func updateCounter() {
    timerLabel.text = String(swiftCounter--)
```

Erro states:

> '--' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3

I realise I have to convert `--` it to `x -= 1` (x is the variable). I have tried

```
 func updateCounter() {
        timerLabel.text = String(swiftCounter -= 1)

    }
```

to reduce the counter by 1 second, but my counter (timerLabel) just goes blank.

What is the new Swift syntax for my situation please?

*** UPDATE: ***

I also added a condition that my timer stop when it reaches zero (0), I failed to do this previously and my timer went into negative territory. My amended code as follows:

```
func updateCounter() {
    swiftCounter -= 1
    timerLabel.text = String(swiftCounter)

    if swiftCounter == 0 {
        swiftTimer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps anyone with a similar situation ;)

Comment: Tip: By convention, name variables start with a lowercase letter (this makes it easy to differentiate them from classes), i.e. `swiftCounter` instead of `SwiftCounter`

Comment: yes. absolutely right. amended my variable. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the logic onto 2 lines, because you're decrementing and saving and then converting to string for display and that's 2 different things:

```
SwiftCounter -= 1
timerLabel.text = String(SwiftCounter)
```

Comment: The decrement needs to be done after setting the text to have the same effect as the current code

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's a warning, not an error.

Just insert an extra line.

```
func updateCounter() {
   SwiftCounter -= 1
   timerLabel.text = String(SwiftCounter)
```

Comment: Yes. A Warning. Thanks. Your solution works. I actually had `func updateCounter() {
        
        SwiftCounter -= 1
        timerLabel.text = "\(SwiftCounter)"
        
    }` which also works, but your solution looks cleaner.

Comment: Why not just `String(SwiftCounter - 1)`

Comment: each time the timer fires it would always have the same result @khuong291 you need to decrement `SwiftCounter` somewhere...

Comment: Upvoted, other solution came in a slight bit earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I edit youre function:

```
 func updateCounter() {
    SwiftCounter -= 1
    timerLabel.text = String(SwiftCounter)
 }
```

Comment: Upvoted, other solution came in a slight bit earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
postfix func --(inout num: Int) {
 num = num - 1
 }

var a = 5

for _ in 0...4{
print(--a)
}
```